# Are stack overflow errors possible with a void method?

Tags: java, recursion

Ideally, void return types would imply that keeping the stack around is not necessary. In practice, is that so?

Comment: Just because a method has a return type of void doesn't mean that it takes no space on the stack... what about all the locals? In short: yes, stack overflow errors are entirely possible in void methods, and it should be very easy for you to demonstrate that.

Comment: Try this `void test() { test(); }`

Comment: It seems that void methods are easily made tail-recursive, so while possible, are these errors easily avoidable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are possible. A stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds the stack bound.

For example

```
void helloWorld() { helloWorld();}
```

This will cause Infinite recursion and thus stack overflow.

Also Java does not support tail recursion optimization.

Comment: It seems that `void` methods are easily made tail-recursive, so while possible, are these errors easily avoidable?

Comment: I see. Java does not support tail recursion optimization. Therefore the compiler does not translate your tail recursive function into a loop (for example scala supports it). You need to have your code changed.